# Thread scheduler that can batch file operations on the same drive to the same thread?

Tags: .net, parallel-processing, system.reactive

I'd like to use the Rx extensions to handle the parallelizing of long, file-bound operations.

The workflow is something along these lines:

- search for a given file pattern on several drives (let's assume each drive is on a separate physical device)
- for each matching file found, queue the long file operation *to the same thread as for the other files on the same drive* - hopefully minimizing random seeks.
- operations on files on different drives should be queued to different threads to allow for parallel processing.

My question is: What Rx scheduler (or combination of schedulers) should I use ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this, it's very useful to realize that each Rx observable subscription works serially. That is, for a single subscription of a single observable, you can be sure that the `onNext` delegate of one item completes before `onNext` for the following item starts.

By default, the `onNext` delegate is executed on the current thread (the one that calls `OnNext()`), but you can change that by using `ObserveOn()`.

What this means for you is that you should create a separate observable for each physical drive and observe each on a separate thread. One way to do that, if you have a single observable of operations to execute is to use `GroupBy()`.

Which specific scheduler to use? I think it pretty much doesn't matter. `ObserveOn()` seems to use `ScheduleLongRunning()` if it's available, which for the most common schedulers means it will create a new thread for observing.

Putting all that together, your code could look something like:

```
operations.GroupBy(op => op.Drive)
          .Select(o => o.ObserveOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default))
          .Do(o => o.Subscribe(op => op.Execute()))
          .Subscribe();
```

(Assuming `operations` is observable of your operation type, that has `Drive` property and `Execute()` method.)